# Getting an error trying to install ibm_db via npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am using windows os. I have no admin rights in the system I am working.
I was following this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/pd?lang=en.

But got this error
npm ERR! ibm_db@0.0.18 install: `node installer/driverInstall.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the ibm_db@0.0.18 install script 'node installer/driverInstall.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ibm_db package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node installer/driverInstall.js npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs ibm_db npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls ibm_db npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: be more precise about your error

Comment: Hi I tried to install ibm_db. Now I have successfully installed it. have used nodejs V0.12.7 and npm 3.8.5 . and installed it without giving -g i.e. locally now its working fine for me.

Comment: Hi Balaji Thank you

Comment: sounds good finally you solved it by your own

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed it. Have used nodejs V0.12.7 and npm 3.8.5 and installed it without giving -g i.e. locally now its working fine for me.